# submit button arrays in PHP

Tags: php

```
<div id='Descp'><?php echo $rows['productName'];?></div><!--decpx-->
<div id='buynow'><input type='submit' name='buyNow[]' id='buyNow' class='buynow' value='Buy' /></div>
```

My question is, is it possible to create arrays of submit buttons like above? Simply the need is to assign a submit button to capture the product type user picks and then redirect to another page to buy.

Second point is using `foreach` will be a good method to capture the clicked button response?

Thanks

Comment: exactly what you want for submit button

Comment: @NitishKumar as I mentioned the 'productName' is dynamic content and will have a button infront. Essentially user clicks this button infront which takes him to another page. Buttons here can not be hard coded as it will automatically placed as a new 'productName' or a product is listed. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id='Descp'><?php echo $rows['productName'];?></div><!--decpx-->
<div id='buynow'><input type='submit' name='buyNow[]' id='buyNow' class='buynow' value='Buy' /></div>
```

use  instead of

```
<div id='Descp'><?php echo $rows['productName'];?></div><!--decpx-->
<div id='buynow'><a href="your.php?id="<?php echo $rows['productId']; ?>">Buy</a></div>
```

on your.php get product id and process them.

Comment: can you pls give me a clue as to what should be there on 'your.php' ? do I need to assign $rows['productId'] to a session and carry to your.php or what? thanks

Comment: on that page where u submitting form

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with standard form submission. The submit button you hit is the only one that gets sent. So really you could just set a value on that input and use that for your redirect. There's no need for an array.

Unless I've misunderstood your question.

If I was implementing this system I would not use submit buttons for this action. I would prefer to use an anchor with a well formed URL. So this would be something like:

```
http://www.example.com/products/PRODUCT-ID/checkout
```

This URL has everything you need to know. The ID of the product (so you can access it's price, title, whatever else) and also it tells you the action: checkout.

Comment: may be my articulation is not great except the comment on the submit button. Even if I use 'button' instead of 'submit' how do I create an array so I can get what the 'productName' that the user wants to buy in this case? Since 'productName' content is dynamic I can't hardcode the submit (or 'button' type) buttons.

Comment: Hang on, and I'll add some additional info to my answer.